# Weblogic 12 get eclipse error when tried to deploy

Tags: java, oracle, eclipselink, weblogic12c

When i tried to deploy an application in weblogic, he give-me the follow exception:

> Substituted for missing class Exception [EclipseLink-7298] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd) -
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: The mapping [associated] from the embedded ID class
>   [class br.com.webproj.web.model.associated.pk.AssmaintainPK] is an
>   invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with
>   an embedded ID specification (attribute [AssmaintainPK] from the
>   source [class br.com.webproj.web.model.associated.AssMaintain]) can
>   only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or
>   change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.

In my `persistence.xml` i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="Web_PU">
        <jta-data-source>JDBC/WEB</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>web-Model.jar</jar-file>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <!-- Cache Enabled -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager"
                value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics"
                value="true" />

            <!-- I TRIED INCLUDING THIS, BUT NOT SOLVE -->
            <property name="eclipselink.exclude-eclipselink-orm"
                value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions"
                value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.orm.validate.schema"
                value="false" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I think this error occurs because the weblogic use the eclipse link, and the project an other version of jpa. But the error is in a jar included in project and i cant change and see the code. If the problem is this, what i can do to dont use the eclipse link of weblogic (obs: in JBoss the project runs normally).